Persistence and Resilience - Is / Are?
Colloquially,

"persistence and resilience is a choice I make"

sounds better than

"persistence and resilience are choices I make"

I know verb subject agreement dictates "are" for plural nouns but I can't help but feels the former sounds better.

It depends on whether you're thinking of them together (like "peanut butter and jelly") or they're independent choices.

Usually they go hand in hand no? But seems like these are words that can be both

Could you have chosen to be persistent but not resilient? If so, they don't necessarily go together.

You could reword it to remove doubt: Being persistent and resilient is a choice I make.
